# How to position an element on another?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I would like to position some elements of the same class one on other. Practically, I want to have them in the same position:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sheet"></div>
    <div class="sheet"></div>
    <div class="sheet"></div>
</div>
```

I also want to have these divs horizontally aligned in the center.

```
.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

How would you do this?

edit: Here is what I would like to have, **but** in positioned to center:
[image]

Comment: can you make a picture/image/drawing of what you want ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorrales I added a screenshot of the present state. What I want is the sheets in the center.

Comment: `.sheet { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }`

Comment: @mdesdev I need it in center

Comment: Ok, I'm working on some Fiddle ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/m85td/)**</kbd>

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 450px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.sheet {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 #666;
}
.sheet:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.sheet:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
```

Comment: I like your example more, but I used `id's` as my example also supports IE8 and other legacy browsers.

Comment: @W.D. Id's got nothing to do with legacy browsers and you can't get transform in IE8 ;)

Comment: `:nth-child()` pseudo class isn't supported in IE8, I didn't mean id's, I meant `:nth-child()` pseudo class. And yes, `transform` isn't supported in IE8 and other legacy browsers either.

Comment: No problem. One question though, how can one get such jsfiddle button like in your post? (:

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Not as you need

As SUMAN said, you can use **nth-child(xn)**.

I do not have the time to make the script, but all the informations you need can be found here:
http://dannich.com/lab/css3-pseudo-classes-for-grid-with-dynamic-content/

NOTE: This is certainly not the most compatible option

Good luck!

Comment: I don't see how this is related

Answer (score 1):

My code will also work on **legacy** browsers (such as IE8 etc) (that is why I decided to use `ids`).
If you aren't planning on supporting legacy browsers, let me know and I'll update my code or take a look at **@mdesdev's** answer which is compatible with all **modern** browsers.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ja42G/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sheet" id='sheet1'></div>
    <div class="sheet" id='sheet2'></div>
    <div class="sheet" id='sheet3'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {

    width:150px;
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    z-index:10;

}

.sheet{
    position:absolute; 
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid brown;
    background:red;

}

#sheet1{
    z-index:7;
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    background:blue;
    }

#sheet2{
    z-index:8;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    background:green;
    }

#sheet3{
    z-index:9;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
    }
```

Comment: I don't like the ids, I would like to have classes instead, but the fiddle looks alright except center positioning of the container...

Answer (score 0):

go with the **nth-child(n)** to differentiate between those same class divs

Answer (score 0):

**Use Position Absolute:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/42/)** use css property `position: absolute;` to keep elements above each other.

**Use z-index to arrange which element is above which:**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/44/)** use `z-index: 3;` to defined which element should be shown above which the greater the number the above it will be from those with lesser value in z-index.

**To Rotate user transform rotate**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5q9K8/46/)** use `transform: rotate(-7deg);` to rotate your divs.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you want!

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="sheet" id='sheet1'></div>
    <div class="sheet" id='sheet2'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

.sheet{
    top:auto;
    left:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    position:absolute; 
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border:1px solid brown;
    background:red;

}

#sheet1{
    z-index:7;
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}

#sheet2{
    z-index:8;
    transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```

NOTE: edited from W.D code
Thanks to him to start the code! It makes challenge!

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something just like this. In my case the "sheets" were going to slide apart on click, so I just had them expanded by default for IE8. For other browsers I did something like this:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.sheet {
   position: relative;
}
.sheet:nth-child(1) {
    left: 33%;
}
.sheet:nth-child(3) {
    left: -33%;
}
```